# QEMU: Solaris 11 / Sparc64 Guest on Linux / X86-64 Host

Tags: linux, virtualization, qemu, solaris-11, ultrasparc

I'm trying to run a Solaris 11 / Sparc64 guest on a Linux/x86-64 host. I've cloned the qemu project and configured/compiled it with sparc64 support (./configure --target-list="sparc64-softmmu").

I've tried various examples and tutorials, but everything seems to be written against older versions. Also QEMU Sparc64 support appears to have been improved upon recently, possibly changing the requirements.

Has anyone successfully configured a VM like this before? If so, how did you do it? Do I still need to grab a custom bios?

Comment: I am in a very similar situation and I am considering opening a similar question - I want to test a custom binary on Solaris 11 / Sparc64 guest, using a windows / x86 host.